# Is it possible to find a universal $\delta_U$, such that $|x-y|<\delta_U\Longrightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon, \forall n=\color{red}0,1,2\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f_n(x)$ ($n=1,2,\dots$) are continuous on $[a, b]$,  $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ pointwisely, and $f(x)$ is continous on $[a, b]$. Define $f_0(x)=f(x)$. We know continuous on compact set implies uniformly continuous, hence $f_n(x)$ ($n=\color{red}0, 1,2,\dots$) are uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Then for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, we can find $\delta_0>0, s. t,~|x-y|<\delta_0\Longrightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Similarly, we can find $\delta_n>0, s. t,~|x-y|<\delta_n\Longrightarrow|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$.

My question is,

If we define the set $S=\{\delta_k|k=0,1,2\dots\}$, how can we say about $\inf S$? For exmaple, we can always make $\inf S=0$,

we can find $\delta'>0, s. t,~|x-y|<\delta'\Longrightarrow|f_1(x)-f_1(y)|<\epsilon$. Set $\delta_1=\min(\delta', \frac12\delta_{0})$

we can find $\delta''>0, s. t,~|x-y|<\delta''\Longrightarrow|f_2(x)-f_2(y)|<\epsilon$. Set $\delta_2=\min(\delta'', \frac12\delta_{1})$

Keep going, we can guarantee $\delta_n\le\frac12\delta_{n-1}$, hence $\inf S=0$. But is it possible to construct $\delta_n$ such that $\inf S>0$? If this is possible (or with some additional conditions), then it means we can find a universal $\delta_U$, such that whenever $|x-y|<\delta_U\Longrightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon, \forall n=\color{red}0,1,2\dots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition you are talking about is called equicontinuity.

A simple characterization of when such a $\delta_U$ can be found is given by the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which states roughly that a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ is equicontinuous (i.e. such a $\delta_U$ exists for any $\epsilon>0$), and $sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}sup_{x\in [a,b]}f_n(x)<\infty$, if and only if for any subsequence of $n$, there exists a further subsequence $n_j$ and a continuous function $f$, so that $f_{n_j}\to f$ uniformly, i.e.
$$
\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

In your case the assumption that $sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}sup_{x\in [a,b]}f_n(x)<\infty$ is automatically satisfied if we have equicontinuity.
This can be seen by noting that in particular $f_n(a)$ converges, and is thus bounded by say $M$. Thus, pick $\delta>0$ so that for all $n$, $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<1$. Then, given $x \in [a,a+\delta)$, it holds $|f_n(x)|<M+1$. Proceeding inductively, we may cover the interval $[a,b]$ by finitely many intersecting intervals of radius $\delta$ and conclude there exists a universal constant $R$ so that $|f_n(x)|\leq R$, for all $x\in [a,b], n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, in your case, one can find such a $\delta_U$ for any $\epsilon>0$ $\iff$ every subsequence has a further subsequence along which $f_{n_j}$ converges uniformly to $f$. However, by a standard argument this just implies that the full sequence actually converges, so indeed a necessary and sufficient condition is that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: +1, thank you, I am a little confused when you show equicontinuity implies uniformly bounded, then why it states "$f_n$ is equicontiuous" and "uniformly bounded"? Why not just simply say "$f_n$ is equicontiuous"?

Comment: The implication equicontinuity $\implies $ uniformly bounded only holds in the case of your question (or more generally if there exists some $x$ so that $|f_n(x)| $ is bounded in n), not in general. For instance consider the functions $f_n(x)=n$ which are certainly equicontinuous but not bounded.

Comment: I see, so as long as there is one point $c\in [a,b]$, such that $f_n(c)$ is bounded for all $n$'s, then we can base on this point and do a mesh (or a grid) with the spacing $\delta_U$ to the entire interval $[a,b]$, then use equicontinuity to show it is uniformly bounded. Further, by Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, "unif-bounded"+"equi-cont"$\Rightarrow$"exists some subsequence $f_{n_k}$ is unif-conv". But since my OP assumes $f_n$ pointwise-conv, hence, "pointwise-conv"+"equi-cont"$\Rightarrow$"unif-bounded"$\Rightarrow$"entire sequence $f_n$ unif-conv". Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly it! The assumption of pointwise convergence is really what lets you get such a nice characterisation, as it ensures both that the sequence is uniformly bounded as soon as its equicontinuous, and that all subsequential limits of $f_n$ must coincide with $f$, which then allows us to get uniform convergence of the entire sequence.

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need further assumptions. Consider the sequence $f_n \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
nx \quad \text{if } &x \leq \frac{1}{n}, \\
2-nx \quad \text{if } &x \in [\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}], \\
0 \quad &\text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
(The graph of the function is a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(\frac{1}{n}, 1)$ and back down to $(0,\frac{2}{n})$.)

We have that the $f_n$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ and converge (pointwise) to $f_0 \equiv 0$. But

$$
|f_n(0) - f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)| = 1
$$
for all $n \geq 1$, so a uniform $\delta$ cannot exist.

I think what you want is that your sequence along with the limit forms an *equicontinuous* family of functions. One condition that works is uniform convergence, see e.g., here: [Uniformly continuous implies equicontinuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205291/uniformly-convergent-implies-equicontinuous)

Another thing that works is if the functions are Hölder (or Lipschitz) continous with the same constant(s), see e.g., here: [Hölder Condition and equicontinuity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608192/h%C3%B6lder-condition-and-equicontinuity)

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: +1, thank you for this nice example, yes, that's what I mean. I know this won't hold in general, so I am asking under what additional condition to make this statement true.